# Unity3d WWWForm only works from Start()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the below code which works fine and sends the data to the server as required:

```
IEnumerator Start () {
        Diffculty d = Diffculty.getInstance ();
        int level = d.getDiffculty ();
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField( "highscore", 1000);
        form.AddField( "name", stringToEdit);
        form.AddField( "level", level);
        WWW download = new WWW( url, form );
        yield return download;
        if((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(download.error))) {
            Debug.Log("Error downloading: " + download.error );
        } else {
            Debug.Log(download.text);
            doWindow0 = false;
        }
    }
```

However I now want this code to be trigger on the press of a button in a guiwindow so have the below code.

```
IEnumerator senddata(){
        Diffculty d = Diffculty.getInstance ();
        int level = d.getDiffculty ();
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField( "highscore", 1000);
        form.AddField( "name", stringToEdit);
        form.AddField( "level", level);
        WWW download = new WWW( url, form );
        yield return download;
        if((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(download.error))) {
            Debug.Log("Error downloading: " + download.error );
        } else {
            Debug.Log(download.text);
            doWindow0 = false;
        }
    }
    void DoWindow0(int windowID) {
        stringToEdit = GUILayout.TextField (stringToEdit, 25);
        if (GUILayout.Button ("Submit Score")) {
            senddata();
        }
    }
    void OnGUI() {
        //doWindow0 = GUI.Toggle(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 20), doWindow0, "Window 0");
        if (doWindow0)
            GUI.Window(0, windowRect, DoWindow0, "");

    }
```

However when I press the button ("submit score") nothing seems to happen and the data is not received by the server

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're not calling StartCoroutine(sendData()). Calling send data as you have only returns the IEnumerator value required to loop through the method, where as StartCoroutine uses the IEnumerator value to actually complete the method.